# Avoid ambiguity in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a C++ wrapper alongside my C project.

So, for example, I have `"window.h"` which has the standard C include guard. It requires `<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>` as well as some third party library includes.

Then, I have `"window.hpp"` which depends on `"window.h"`, but uses C++ `#pragma once` and requires `<cstdlib>` and `<string>` for the C++ implementations.

I am running into an ambiguity issue where the C/C++ standard implementations are conflicting, and I'm not quite sure what to do about it. You can see I tried to fix this by simply checking if `__cplusplus` was defined, and only adding the C++ headers if that's the case.

The idea is that you can just do `using namespace LittleEngine::utils;` and it will include SDL and GLEW for you, as well as add some wrapper features for creating a window, for example; where it uses C++ features like classes instead of the C implemented methods.

For sanity's sake, that's why these are separate files and not just one header file that adds compatibility for both C and C++ with `extern "C" { ... }`.

"window.h"

```c
#if __cplusplus
#pragma once
#endif

#ifndef LITTLE_ENGINE_UTILS_WINDOW_H_
#define LITTLE_ENGINE_UTILS_WINDOW_H_

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#if __cplusplus
#   include <cstdio>
#   include <string>
#else
#   include <stdio.h>
#   include <string.h>
#endif

typedef struct {
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_GLContext context;
    SDL_Event event;
} Engine_GLWindow_t;

enum Engine_Window_Renderer {
    VULKAN,
    OPENGL
};

int Engine_CreateGLWindow(const char* title, Engine_GLWindow_t* window)
{
    // Initialize SDL
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize SDL.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    // Configure window flags
    Uint32 flags = 0;

    flags |= SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL;

    SDL_Window* sdlwin = SDL_CreateWindow(
        title,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        800,
        600,
        flags
    );

    if(!sdlwin)
        return -1;

    window->window = sdlwin;

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 6);
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    SDL_GLContext context;
    if((context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window->window)) != NULL)
        window->context = context;
    else
    {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window->window);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize the GL context.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    GLenum glewCode = glewInit();

    if(glewCode != GLEW_OK)
    {
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(window->context);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window->window);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", glewGetErrorString(glewCode));
        return -1;
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    SDL_ShowWindow(sdlwin);
    
    return 0;
}

int Engine_DestroyGLWindow(Engine_GLWindow_t* window)
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(window->context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window->window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
#endif
```

"windows.hpp"

```cpp
#pragma once

/*
file included as:
engine.hpp
...
namespace LittleEngine {
    namespace utils {
#       include "utils.hpp" // -> #include "windows.hpp"
    }
}
*/

#include "window.h"

#include <cstdint>

class GLWindow {
public:

    GLWindow(std::string title)
    {
        Engine_CreateGLWindow(title.c_str(), &this->window_data);
    }

    GLWindow(std::string title, bool& success)
    {
        if(Engine_CreateGLWindow(title.c_str(), &this->window_data) == 0)
            success = true;
    }

    ~GLWindow()
    {
        Engine_DestroyGLWindow(&this->window_data);
    }

    Engine_GLWindow_t* getWindowData()
    {
        return &this->window_data;
    }

protected:
    Engine_GLWindow_t window_data;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <LittleEngine/engine.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
{
    // COMMENTED CODE WORKS BTW
    // Engine_GLWindow_t window;
    // Engine_CreateGLWindow("LittleBird", &window);

    LittleEngine::utils::GLWindow window("LittleBird");

    bool should_run = true;
    const LittleEngine::utils::Uint8* keys = nullptr;
    
    while (should_run)
    {
        while (LittleEngine::utils::SDL_PollEvent(&window.getWindowData()->event))
            if (window.getWindowData()->event.type == LittleEngine::utils::SDL_QUIT)
                should_run = false;

        // ensure that SDL2 updated the keyboard state
        LittleEngine::utils::SDL_PumpEvents();

        // // automatically update window size
        // UpdateWindowSize(&window);

        // SDL2 should automatically clear this memory after each loop
        keys = LittleEngine::utils::SDL_GetKeyboardState(0);

        // black background color
        LittleEngine::utils::glClearColor(0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 1.00f);

        // red background color if pressing W
        if(keys[LittleEngine::utils::SDL_SCANCODE_W])
            LittleEngine::utils::glClearColor(1.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 1.00f);
        
        LittleEngine::utils::glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        LittleEngine::utils::SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window.getWindowData()->window);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: logs]

Comment: @drescherjm thanks but that didn't take any of the errors away :(

Comment: Are those includes needed for the prototypes in that header? Or are they needed for the actual implementations (which didn't need to be in the header)?

Comment: Always address the first error first. I can see from the window you’re not looking at the first error. Anything after the first error is always suspect and potentially invalid.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I apologize for how unorganized this looks. Essentially, the C header includes SDL and GLEW headers, and then defines a couple of methods. The C++ header just needs to include the C header and call those functions. The problem is ambiguity where C defines and C++ defines cross-contaminate through the C-impl STL and the C++-impl STL.

Comment: As an addition to my last comment, it looks like a jumbled piece of hot garbage because in an effort to try to keep my namespace clear, I put the C include in the C++ header file, which was wrapped in a nested namespace.

Comment: It looks like you're `#include`ing standard headers within your namespace.  Don't do that; you're almost certain to run into linking errors later if you do.  You should essentially never put a `#include` directive inside a namespace; it will cause no end of trouble.

Comment: Why does it need stdio and string, though? I see that e.g. fprintf is called inside the implementation of a function, but I don't see why they are needed for the function prototypes. I remind you this is a header file.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I was having some weird additional errors with compiling it as a static library. Essentially I took C++ out of the picture, just compiled the C files with respect to the .h files, and I was getting unresolved symbol errors even though I was correctly adding the library in GCC/G++. I thought it would make life easier by just implementing them straight into the header files. I did test it and could prove it was linking correctly by adding a single `void test()` method, but eh idk.

Comment: @TyQ. You should get your C code compiling as C code first, before adding C++ to the mix.  At that point, the only thing you'll need is an `extern "C" {}` block around your C functions.  C++ is perfectly happy with C-style `string.h` includes.  They are not your issue.

Comment: Incidentally, `#pragma once` is not standard C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker `#pragma once` isn't standard but is supported by the 3 biggest compilers: GNU, Microsoft, LLVM. Unless you're coding for a very specific and obscure architecture, or embedded systems, it works practically the same if not better than include guards nowadays.

Comment: @TyQ. -- unless you like writing non-portable code, you should use the standard include guards. They work just fine; `#pragma once` is a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @TyQ. -- whoops, forgot to mention: there are build environments (networked source files, for example, where you cannot tell whether one "foo.h" is the same file as another "foo.h" reached through a different network path) where `#pragma once` cannot be implemented, regardless of whether your compiler claims to support it.

Comment: @PeteBecker Idk why you're going off about `#pragma once`. It has no relevance to this post. Either way, both include guards and pragma have their issues. Generally speaking though, most of the time it doesn't matter and all comes down to preference anyway.

Comment: @TyQ. — `#pragma once` fails under circumstances that are hard to recognize and hard to diagnose. It only “comes down to preference” if you ignore it’s weaknesses.

Answer (score 2):

So after some more testing, the answer to my problem was that you have to wrap C header files in `extern "C"` before trying to include them into namespaces.

```cpp
namespace LittleEngine {
    namespace utils {
        extern "C" {
#           include "window.h"
        }
#       include "window.hpp"
    }
}
```

However, even when doing this, it still puts the C-defines at the root namespace, which makes sense I guess.

Edit: Moreover, it does get a lot weirder than just that. In the above example, I can extern-C include the "window.h" file. The second I hop to another file and try to chain impl. this, I get the same error I started out with. TLDR; TIL only C++ includes go in namespaces.

Edit 2: I think it was just GLEW and SDL causing the issue. I hate programming. Why do I do this to myself?

Edit 3: After even more testing.. I think it was. So the biggest changes I made when refactoring is

1. Not including headers in sub-header files. You can do this because of how the Linker works.
2. I took out all the `extern "C"` because all that should theoretically do is disable C++ name wrangling, which doesn't make sense anyway.
3. I simply moved the SDL and GLEW includes out of scope of the namespace and suddenly it works.

Either way, my point still stands. Don't include C headers in C++ namespaces.

If somebody else wants to answer this in a preferably more detailed manner, I would be happy to mark that as the answer.